# Como fazer um filter com javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

tenho um array de objetos e quero fazer um filter para filtrar as properties e retornar apenas as properties com a **lat** e **lon** maior que **0**

Como eu faço isso? Como eu consigo acessar lat e lot?

Eu tentei algo assim mas não funciona:

```
  var filtered = this.properties;
      this.filtered.filter(p => {
        return p.address.geoLocation.location.lat > 0;
      });
```

json:

```
{
properties:[
{
      "usableAreas": 70,
      "listingType": "USED",
      "createdAt": "2017-04-22T18:39:31.138Z",
      "listingStatus": "ACTIVE",
      "id": "7baf2775d4a2",
      "parkingSpaces": 1,
      "updatedAt": "2017-04-22T18:39:31.138Z",
      "owner": false,
      "images": [
        "https://resizedimgs.com/crop/400x300/vr.images.sp/f908948bf1d9e53d36c4734d296feb99.jpg",
        "https://resizedimgs.com/crop/400x300/vr.images.sp/bd37e4c09ddd370529489fbbc461dbec.jpg",
        "https://resizedimgs.com/crop/400x300/vr.images.sp/7b86204f34b751c432c878d607c9d618.jpg",
        "https://resizedimgs.com/crop/400x300/vr.images.sp/3b1142cffc13c49a1e7ea766c20a1d52.jpg",
        "https://resizedimgs.com/crop/400x300/vr.images.sp/f519a27d56696febfb77f6398f4484d8.jpg"
      ],
      "address": {
        "city": "",
        "neighborhood": "",
        "geoLocation": {
          "precision": "NO_GEOCODE",
          "location": {
            "lon": 0,
            "lat": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "bathrooms": 1,
      "bedrooms": 2,
      "pricingInfos": {
        "yearlyIptu": "60",
        "price": "276000",
        "businessType": "SALE",
        "monthlyCondoFee": "0"
      }
    }]
```

esse é o metodo get:

```
this.$http
    .get(`properties?_page=${this.page}&_limit=${this.limit}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.properties = this.properties.concat(res.data);
      this.page++;

      if (res.data.length === 0) this.loadMore = false;
      console.log(this.properties);
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
this.filtered = this.properties.filter(p => {
  const {lat, lon} = p.address.geoLocation.location;
  return Math.min(lat, lon) > 0;
});
```

A função `.filter` retorna uma nova array com os valores que passarem a verificação que o `return` envia. Assim, o `Math.min` retorna o valor mínimo dos dois e por isso sendo o menor `> 0` tens a condição resolvida.

Exemplo:

```js
const properties = [{
    "id": "A",
    "address": {
      "city": "",
      "neighborhood": "",
      "geoLocation": {
        "precision": "NO_GEOCODE",
        "location": {
          "lon": 0,
          "lat": 1000
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "B",
    "address": {
      "city": "",
      "neighborhood": "",
      "geoLocation": {
        "precision": "NO_GEOCODE",
        "location": {
          "lon": 100,
          "lat": 100
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "C",
    "address": {
      "city": "",
      "neighborhood": "",
      "geoLocation": {
        "precision": "NO_GEOCODE",
        "location": {
          "lon": 100,
          "lat": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

const filtered = properties.filter(p => {
  const {lat, lon} = p.address.geoLocation.location;
  return Math.min(lat, lon) > 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```